# ReportViewer scroll issues in IE

Tags: report, reportviewer, reporting-services, reportviewer2008

I've deployed a report using reportViewer on my local machine. 
It's a wide report so requires a horizontal scroll bar across the bottom of the report but fits fine vertically. This is fine in FF, however IE renders it with the vertical scrollbar as well and no matter what I do I cant get rid of it! 
Is this a problem with IE? 
Can I not just have a horizontal scrollbar or does IE insist on having both even if the vertical scrollbar does next to nothing?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find the correct answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but is the ReportViewer configured for asynchronous rendering?

This link has some details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090.aspx

With AsyncRendering=true, your report will render inside an IFRAME. It may default to a particular height until it renders and IE isn't recognizing that after the fact.

Try setting it to false - if that's the issue and asynchronous rendering isn't an option for you, there may be a way to programmatically set the initial height of the ReportViewer small enough to avoid those scrollbars.

IE definitely allows just one type of scrollbar (at least IE8 does) - you can try it by resizing the window on the Google homepage and making the window tall but narrow.

Answer (score 2):

If you use IE 11 edge you have this problem.

```css
.repViewer{overflow-y:auto !important;}
```

```html
<rsweb:ReportViewer Height="400px" CssClass="repViewer">
```